# Relaxation of the $\pi^{\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}}$ problem

Tags: number-theory, pi, transcendental-numbers

My friend showed me this fascinating problem:
[Why is it so difficult to determine whether or not $\Large \pi^{\pi^{\pi^\pi}}$ is an integer?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/853457/why-is-it-so-difficult-to-determine-whether-or-not-large-pi-pi-pi-pi).

[Proof that ${\left(\pi^\pi\right)}^{\pi^\pi}$ (and now $\pi^{\left(\pi^{\pi^\pi}\right)}$) is a noninteger.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/390708/proof-that-left-pi-pi-right-pi-pi-and-now-pi-left-pi-pi-pi)

It turns out that we don't know whether $\Large \pi^{\pi^{\pi^{\pi}}}$ is an integer. This is because a) there are very few theorems about combinations of transcendentals and b) the number is too large to reason about computationally.

So I was thinking about a relaxation of the problem. Let $f(a)=\Large a^{a^{a^a}}$. Can we find a rational $q \neq 0$ such that $f(q*\pi)$ or $f(q+\pi)$ is rational?

---

I have tested all $q=p/r$, such that $1 \leq p,r \leq 100,000$ and $q*\pi \leq 2$ and did not find any integer $f(q*\pi)$. The most interesting was $q=18868/37909$, which gave $f(q*\pi) \approx 3$.

Similarly I have tested all $q=p/r$, such that $1 \leq p,r \leq 100,000$ and $|\pi-q| \leq 2$ and did not find any integer $f(\pi-q)$. The most interesting was $q=85186/61765$, which gave $f(\pi-q) \approx 14$.

Comment: I wouldn't call this a "simplification"!  If you expect a positive answer, then it is simpler, because there are more options about where to find one.  But the answer is probably negative, which means you have more to prove instead of more options!

Comment: Yes good point. Would you call it a relaxation instead?